# How can I pass the name of the field in form_error ()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

It's part of my view. Me need transmit input name in  on which i click.
Below is a script that will get the name input after click

```
<div class="form_hint"><?=form_error('this get value from javascript after click')?></div>

        <?php echo form_open("onenews/" . $onenews['id'] . "#signup", $form_reg['main_form']); ?>      
        <?php echo form_input($form_reg['login'], $this->form_validation->set_value('login')) ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form_reg['email'], $this->form_validation->set_value('email')) ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form_reg['password']) ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form_reg['conf_password']) ?>
        <?= MY_Controller:: create_captcha(); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form_reg['captcha']) ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form_reg['submit']) ?>   
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**jq**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var curInput = '';
            $('#form_reg').find('input').on('click', function(){
                curInput = $(this).attr("name");
            });

        })
    </script>
```

Or i must use ajax?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all, but I assume you want to dynamically change the content of the form_hint div. You can't do that with PHP. Once PHP renders the page, it shuts down and does nothing more. So the only way to make PHP show that message is after the form submit, but then you lose your click data. There is a way to save the clicked element in a session for example, but that would be a really bad solution.

So the best solution would probably be to list all the hints in a JavaScript variable, and call the appropriate one upon the click event, and fill the form_hint div with it.

```
$('.form_hint').text(yourAppropriateMessageHere);
```

An example with a hidden div for the login input field with exactly how you described would be:

```
<div class="form_text_login"><?=form_error('login')?></div>
```

JS

```
var loginMessage = $('.form_text_login').text();
// list others here
// then make a tree with switch/case or if/else
if (curInput == 'login') {
    $('.form_hint').text(loginMessage);
}
else if (curInput == 'email') {
    // do the same with the email message, etc.
}
```

Comment: sorry for my english. I see one solution, i can input all error in page on hidden span, after use js for display error. 
<span style="overflow:hidden">error1</span>
<span style="overflow:hidden">error2</span>

Comment: Hi, yes, that will work, you just need a way to differentiate between all the spans - using an id, or a class would be the easiest (like I did with my div)